# Google Analytics in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-analytics-4

I am using firebase analytics GA4 in my flutter project.As of now Event and goals are shown but once install the application use the screen and uninstall it then only show in the firebase Realtime analytics.  What could be causing the problem? (If I didn't uninstall it's never shown events and goals in my analytics)

```
static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

analytics.logEvent(
  name: "selected_artist",
  parameters: filterOutNulls(
    <String, Object?>{"_ITEM_NAME": getStartModel.name}
  )
);
```

I tried the above code to use events in my project

Answer (score 0):

Note that the events typically take quite awhile to get 'ingested'. As per google, it can take 24-48hours. Hence, perhaps you should log an event and then wait 24-48hours to see if it appears before uninstalling?

[Google Analytics 4 docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en#:%7E:text=Many%20of%20your%20reports%20and,from%20your%20website%20or%20app.)

Comment: Hi @Roy I need to check realtime analytics but data shown only after uninstall the application. In website I am using same process, data  show properly. If I do an action in my screen I need to the analytics on realtime.